# Static Text and embed text both greyed out Flash CC professional

Tags: text, adobe-flash

I have ***Flash professional CC build 14.1.0.96*** and I'm trying to perform a free transform on some text; however when I do this, the text disappears.

Iv'e googled around, which suggests I need to use static text, or if i'm using dynamic text, I need to embed my font.

My problem is that both the static text and the embed font options are greyed out.

How can I either embed text or select static text?

Comment: This is less a graphic design question and more of a "how do I use this tool" question. Perhaps it would be better asked in the SuperUser stack exchange? Also, have you read the Adobe Help documentation for Flash? http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/embed-fonts-consistent-text-appearance.html

Comment: ok moved to SuperUser; sorry I but I'm using flash as a vector drawing package, and thought, others might do this too.

Comment: some might use Flash for vector artwork but really it's major strength is in animation/interaction. Illustrator (or even Inkscape) are much more robust vector artwork tools.

Answer (score 2):

It is your file type. When you create a new doc, make sure to make correct choice... ie. create an Actionscript3 file and not an html file. HTML canvas greys out the text options and a lot more.